# Why is a laser beam path visible when it's impacted through a solution of Sodium bicarbonate?

Tags: laser

In school we did this experiment. We impacted a laser beam through a solution of sodium bicarbonate and the path of laser was visible in it.

Does it have anything to do with coloids? But is this solution a coloid?

Comment: Was the sodium bicarbonate completely dissolved? Or could some of it have remained in suspension?

Comment: I don't recall. But I think it was completely dissolved.

Comment: What you observe is likely just light scatter from the slightly turbid solution. I will try the experiment later today, after coffee, and see how it goes. Anyway, what was the purpose of the experiment?

Comment: The purpose was to see the laser path actually.